# How to change namespace when broadcasting status to Sender

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

After media starts playing, I am broadcasting the status to the sender using the broadcastStatus() method like this: mediaManager.broadcastStatus(true);

In my log, I see that the namespace is generated by default and is: urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media.

Is it possible to change this and pass a specific namespace? I try, without success:
window.messageBus = castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus('mynamespace);

and

cast.receiver.media.MEDIA_NAMESPACE = 'mynamespace';

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The media namespace is a reserved namespace that is understood by the SDK. You can create a new namespace (i.e. you cannot change the namespace used as the media namespace) and use that for your own data exchange.